# Background image not covering full screen

Tags: html, css, image, background, whitespace

I'm building an one page scroll down type website, where each slide is a page.
In the last slide, the background image is somehow geting cuted and there's just a white space. The css used on the id of that slide:

```
#seven {background:url(../img/camara_view.JPG) bottom no-repeat fixed; }
```

Here's a print:
http://postimg.org/image/489mxfagt/

Any solutions?

Comment: It may be because of #seven not stretch up to the bottom of the page. If you provide HTML and relevant CSS, we can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-scale property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Answer (score 0):

If you're supporting modern browsers, you can do the following.

```
#seven {
    background-size: cover /* contain */ /* width in px/em/rem ie 50rem 20rem */
}
```

Alternatively, you can put your image in an `img` tag within a container, position the container using either `fixed` or `absolute` positioning. Next, give it a width of `100%` and height of `100%` or `top, left, right, bottom` a value of `0`, while hiding the overflow. Lastly, set the `img` width to `width: auto` and `height: 100%` with `display: block`.[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6YHb/).

Answer (score 0):

using css background image

```
 html { 
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

else you can try some other way below code works fine from ie7

css code

```
#bg {
position: fixed;
top: -50%; 
left: -50%; 
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
}

 #bg img {
position:absolute;
top:25%;left:25%; 
right:25%;bottom:25%;
margin:auto; 
min-width:50%;
min-height:50%;}
```

html code

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/Body-bg.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  .bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }

this will eliminate issue